# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Node' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

the compiler isn't recognizing my Node class for some reason even though I have them all in the same namespace :/ The error message in the title is referring to this line `static Node sampleTree()`

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using bfs_and_dfs;

namespace bfs_and_dfs
{
    partial class Program
    {
        static Node sampleTree()
        {
            Node root = new Node("A", 
            new Node("B", new Node("C"), new Node("D")),
            new Node("E",
                new Node("F"), new Node("G", new Node("H"), null))
            );

            return root;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Node tree = sampleTree(); bfs_traversal(tree);
        }
    }
}
```

Node.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace bfs_and_dfs
{
    public class Node
    {
        public Node left;
        public Node right;
        public string data;

        // For non-leaf nodes
        public Node(string data, Node left, Node right)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        // For leaf nodes
        public Node(string data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
        }
    }
}
```

BFS_traversal.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace bfs_and_dfs
{
    partial class Program
    {
        const int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;
        const int A_ASCII = 65;

        static void bfs_traversal(Node startNode)
        {
            // dangerously assumes all nodes contain
            // one of 26 letters in the alphabet
            bool [] visited = new bool[ALPHABET_SIZE];
            // Array.Fill(visited, false);

            Queue<Node> q = new Queue<Node>();
            q.Enqueue(startNode);
            visited[char.Parse(startNode.data.ToUpper()) - A_ASCII] = true;

            while (q.Count > 0)
            {
                Node node = q.Dequeue();
                System.Console.Write(node.data + " ");

                if (node.left != null 
                && !visited[char.Parse(node.left.data.ToUpper()) - A_ASCII])
                {
                    q.Enqueue(node.left);
                    visited[char.Parse(node.left.data.ToUpper()) - A_ASCII] = true;
                }

                if (node.right != null
                && !visited[char.Parse(node.right.data.ToUpper()) - A_ASCII])
                {
                    q.Enqueue(node.right);
                    visited[char.Parse(node.right.data.ToUpper()) - A_ASCII] = true;
                }
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I am using Visual Studio Code as my text editor.

Comment: How does this method `bfs_traversal(tree);` look like? I can compile without this in Visual Studio (not VS Code).

Comment: Did you save Node.cs? I fall to that trap, where in VS Code everything was fine but the compilation fails, and thought that I reproduced the problem, but no, it went away as soon as I saved Node.cs and re-issued a dotnet build.

Comment: This must be something to do with the VSC.  Why do you have the `using bfs_and_dfs;` in Program.cs? That same namespace is also defined in the program.cs.

Comment: Yeah, Oguz I have the text editor on auto-save. And also, Thomas, I will update my question with the code to that right now :)

Comment: @sanmcp because that was part of the tutorial I saw.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XU_ugVTSjSE&t=246s

Comment: @FreezeWer I just looked at that video.  Unless I'm watching a continuation of a previous video,  I don't see any reason for that Program.cs class to be a partial class and don't see the `using bfs_and_dfs;` in that video though.  Also, that tutorial should follow the C# naming conventions.